# Error in redirect_uri_mismatch with FourSquare

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, foursquare, spring-social

I am using spring social for connecting my app with foursquare facing error mentioned in attached image while specifying Callback URL in given image. For the same location when I specify "localhost:8080/CabFMS" then its working fine. Please help to resolve this error.

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What callback URL are you including in your call to `https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate`? Make sure it matches your callback URL *exactly*, up to the inclusion of "http://", and having no trailing '/'